# Is it possible to use online databases in a local project?

Tags: remote-access, database

Here is my database connection:

```
// connect to database and select database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "spy";
$dbh_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$dbh_conn->exec("set names utf8");
$dbh_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

It works fine since the database is exists in the local. Now I've uploaded the database on a server and I want to use that online database *(instead of the local one)*. Is it possible? If yes, what should I write as `servername`?

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible,

Tough I would suggest you to take down all these info you've submitted here and simply replace "localhost" to the Access host you've published.

You don't want people to know you've a sweet unsecured database at that IP :)

It's funny you underlined the answer ;)